# Please help, what font is this

Tags: font-identification

[image: script font used on a tag]

Please help me identifying this font.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. There are things you can do to answer this question. Recolour the image, separate all the letters and then upload the resultant image to [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). Then -- if that doesn't actually find anything, report what it *did* find here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a freehand 575 font.. not exact

[image]

[Freehand 575](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/freehand-575/freehand-575/)